# How can I use a 'next generation' java data object style together with interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, immutability, field, encapsulation

I'm writing most of my immutable data objects in the following style, which is somtimes described as ['next generation'](http://codemonkeyism.com/generation-java-programming-style/) or 'functional':

```
public class Point {
   public final int x;
   public final int y;

   public Point(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}
```

I would like to use the same style for data objects specified by interfaces:

```
public interface Point {
   public final int x;
   public final int y;
}

public class MyPoint {
   public MyPoint(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}

public class Origin {
   public Origin() {
      this.x = 0;
      this.y = 0;
   }
}
```

But this is not allowed by java, which gives an error in the interface code as well as the implementations.

I can change my code to

```
public interface Point {
   public int x();
   public int y();
}

public class MyPoint {
   private int mx, my;
   pulic MyPoint(int x, int y) {
      mx = x;
      my = y;
   }
   public int x() {return mx;}
   public int y() {return my;}
}

public class Origin {
   public int x() {return 0;}
   public int y() {return 0;}
}
```

But it is more code, and I don't think it gives nearly the same feeling of simplicity in the API.

Can you see a path out of my dilemma? Or do you personally use a third, even simpler style?

(I'm not really interested in a discussion of mutable/immutable, getterSetter/new-style or private/public fields.)

Comment: Am I missing something, or is "next generation" simply "immutable types"?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably fair to say.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather switch to use inheritance or delegation

```
public class Point {
 public final int x;
 public final int y;

 public Point(int x, int y) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
 }
}
```

Inheritance

```
public class MyPoint extends Point {
   public MyPoint (int x, int y) {
     super (x, y);
   }
   ....
}

public class Origin extends Point {
   public Origin () {
     super (0, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but there might be some fields that aren't supposed to be settable by the user. E.g. the field `height` in `Tree`. I suppose then you would set the constructor in the "Main class" to protected?

Comment: I did not really get you. In which object you have additional fields?

Comment: Say we have `Node` with the public final fields `value` and `height`. We also have the two subclasses `Branch` and `Leaf`. In the constructor of `Branch` `height` is calculated from its children, and in the constructor of `Leaf` it is set to `0`. We obviously don't want the user to be able to call `new Node(int value, int height)`. At best the shouldn't even know about it.